# ReactJS: label don't go up when browser uses auto filled in input

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an application made with ReacJS and Tailwind CSS that has the following input:

[image]

[image]

The first image refers to the input with data automatically filled in by the browser. Which means the label doesn't go up (as happens in the second image).

The code responsible for showing the input is:

```
<input
              className="block px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-4 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer"
              id="password"
              placeholder="Senha"
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label 
              htmlFor="password"
              className="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-2 z-10 origin-[0] bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-2 peer-focus:px-2 peer-focus:text-blue-600 peer-focus:dark:text-blue-500 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:-translate-y-1/2 peer-placeholder-shown:top-1/2 peer-focus:top-2 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4 rtl:peer-focus:translate-x-1/4 rtl:peer-focus:left-auto start-1">Password</label>
```

How can I solve this problem? Making the label automatically go up when the browser uses the autocomplete function?

Comment: could you please show me the `setState` part on this component?

Comment: so I often faced this issue when using mui input component, and I resolved it by setting the initial value (empty string - `""`) in `setState`. `const [password, setPassword] = setState("");` Please try to use it at your side.

Comment: Will you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example? It seems to be working correctly when I tried to replicate the issue in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-autofill-label?file=app%2Fpage.tsx).